# apt-get installation, path directory and running dependency programs

Tags: apt, install-from-source

I am very new to Ubuntu and please bear with me if I present a very layman's version of explanation.

My OS: Ubuntu 11.10 server, 64bit version

I need to use three tools `samtools`, `bowtie` and `tophat`. However `tophat` is dependent upon samtools and bowtie. The dependency factor is - to ascertain where exactly the path to the above two tools (samtools and bowtie) are located.

Now, I can install samtools and bowtie using `sudo apt-get install` however

- I dont know exactly where the library paths exists for samtools or bowtie
- According to the tophat installation notes, I am to extract the tool from compressed file, change dir into this file and ./configure; BUT I dont see the ./configure script in the extracted directory

[Samtools](http://samtools.sourceforge.net/) and [Bowtie](http://bowtie-bio.sourceforge.net/index.shtml) and [Tophat](http://tophat.cbcb.umd.edu/tutorial.html) are found on their sites, this is the [installation method](http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/4885/installation-of-tophat-1-1-4) I am trying to follow.

Answer (score 1):

To find out where the libraries are installed, you could try `dpkg -L samtools` and the same for bowtie